# Fork and exec not producing correct results

Tags: python, c, rss, exec, fork

I'm going through Head First C. Nearly done! But ugh, I'm so tired of these exercises not working. In the chapter on Processes and System Calls, we download a python program and then run our code, which will fork and exec the python three times, each time it should search an rss feed for the phrase we wrote on the command line. The rss feeds are environment variables. I chose 2 from BBC and 1 from StackOverflow, of course.

The book shows that we should be able to call the program with the phrase we want to search and on the next line all the matches will display. I have been getting either no results or strange results and unduplicatable results. Sorry the includes aren't looking right.

The python code I downloaded from https://github.com/dogriffiths/rssgossip/zipball/master.

Is the problem the code, or Cygwin, or python or just me????

The C program:

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < string.h>
#include < errno.h>
#include < unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *feeds[] = {"http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/us_and_canada/rss.xml",
                    "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds",
                    "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml"};
    int times = 3;
    char *phrase = argv[1];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<times; i++) {
        char var[255];
        sprintf(var, "RSS_FEED=%s", feeds[i]);
        char *vars[] = {var, NULL};

        //FORK() AND EXEC()
        pid_t pid = fork(); 
        if (pid == -1) {    
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not fork process: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        if (!pid) {         // pid == 0 for child process
            if (execle("/usr/bin/python", "/usr/bin/python", "./rssgossip.py", phrase, NULL, vars) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't run script: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the following results came from the same compile of this program. The feeds did change sometimes but I chose words that I saw in more than one feed, yet only once did I get more than one result.

The one for the whales in nets was from this rss entry on 2 lines but it's not formatting for me:

How to rescue whales tangled in nets
The Canadian team rescuing whales from fishing nets

so it should have returned both lines.

The ones where the result is after `$` were like this: I entered the command on the line above, and it did nothing for a second, then gave me a new prompt and the result on the next line. Then it would stop. I waited a while to see if it was still searching. I didn't realize I could enter a new command so I ctrl-C'd.

Cygwin:

```
XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ gcc newshound.c -o newshound

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ./newshound 'website'

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ./newshound 'mobile'

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ jquery mobile button icons-36-white.png shows wrong icon
^C

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ./newshound 'mobile'

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ./newshound 'website'

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ./newshound 'the'

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ AUDIO: Gunman's mother: 'My heart is broken'
China 'unblocks' Twitter and others
VIDEO: Exploring the violent world of GTA5
Make-It-Yourself: The rise of the micro-manufacturers
Digital Indians: The final Hangout
Could high-end camping gear save lives around the world?
"Unrecognized selector sent to instance", even though the instance is the right type
ASPNET MVC : Getting rid of apple-touch-icon errors : The controller for path Controller1/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png was not found
Error deleting files with FineUploader when using more than one uploader in the same jsp
Javascript on click not showing the elements it should
Sum a column that corresponds a aggregate from a column of another table
Trying To Find The Cause Of Very Slow MySQL Query
How can I quickly find the first element in a list that matches a conditional?
Meteor.js: how to pass the data context of one helper to another helper?
Iam using javamail IAP but I dont know how to get Sent or another folder except inbox
^C

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ./newshound 'net'

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ How to rescue whales tangled in nets
^C

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ^C

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
      416       1     416        416  ?       1005   Sep 20 /usr/bin/mintty
     5852     416    5852       5664  pty0    1005   Sep 20 /usr/bin/bash
     5564    5852    5564        800  pty0    1005 13:31:44 /usr/bin/ps

XPS410 ~/c-bin
XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     4348    5852    4348       5192  pty0    1005 13:31:52 /usr/bin/ps
      416       1     416        416  ?       1005   Sep 20 /usr/bin/mintty
     5852     416    5852       5664  pty0    1005   Sep 20 /usr/bin/bash
     2644       1    5856       1288  pty0    1005 13:31:51 /usr/bin/python2.6
     1384       1    5856        872  pty0    1005 13:31:51 /usr/bin/python2.6
     5864       1    5856       5344  pty0    1005 13:31:51 /usr/bin/python2.6

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$ How to rescue whales tangled in nets
ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     3980    5852    3980       4348  pty0    1005 13:32:56 /usr/bin/ps
      416       1     416        416  ?       1005   Sep 20 /usr/bin/mintty
     5852     416    5852       5664  pty0    1005   Sep 20 /usr/bin/bash

XPS410 ~/c-bin
$
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the python code externally? If it works from the command line with the right arguments, then you know the python program is not the problem.

Comment: From looking at python, I see only text in title tags should be a hit.  That explains it! Thanks for your suggestion! Make it an answer and I'll pick it.

Comment: You're welcome! Will add the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest doing is checking if the python code works externally.

This should also give you an idea of what the input to the program should be. Python source code should be pretty easy to understand too if you get lost.

If it works from the command line with the right arguments, then you know the python program is not the problem. This should allow you to focus on where you're problem is actually coming from.